# Discord Как получить username с Discord ID

Tags: c#, get, discord, discord-api

У меня есть много Discord ID. Хотелось бы получить из ID -> user#1234. В официальном API  нашел https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-user , но как конкретно оно работает так и не разобрался. Пробывал сделать через url  запрос https://discord.com/users/620870096822000041(id изменен)
Но работает только в том случае если есть авторизация на сайте Discord и есть **общие** сервера/друзья с этим id хотелось бы это реализовать либо С#, либо запросом. Зарание спасибо.

Comment: `если есть авторизация на сайте Discord и есть общие сервера/друзья с этим id` А вы хотите без этих условий? Мне кажется это специально сделано в целях безопасности.

Comment: @ГеннадийП , https://discord.id/ вот  сайт который это реализует, однако использование этого сайта мне кажется нецелесообразно из-за объёма информации. Конечно я могу ошибаться и если это так то хотелось бы понять почему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы тебе узнать инфу об юзерах то тебе надо делать запрос на https://discord.com/api/v8/users/ID
И в заголовок авторизации вставить токен бота, которого можно создать [тут](https://discord.com/developers/applications) и всё будет выводить.
[image: Пример]

Comment: Да, именно так я и реализовал, данный ответ верный.